# Find the best match in JSON file with keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, keyword

I don't know how to explain that, and I don't know if it's possible because I don't find what I want on the internet.

For exemple I have this JSON of command

```js
{
    "gif": [
      "gif","show","bot"
    ],
    "doc": [
      "show","doc","bot"
    ],
    "weather": [
      "show","actual","weather"
    ]
}
```

And a user enter this message:

"Hi bot can you show me the actual weather ?"

How I can code for that my function will return the command("weather" in this case) with the best keyword match that there is in the user's message ?

Hope my question was a bit cleary

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate through your JSON and then use `array#every` to check for existence of each word of your array inside your string using `string#includes`.

```js
var keyWords = { "gif": [ "gif","show","bot" ], "doc": [ "show","doc","bot" ], "weather": [ "show","actual","weather" ] };
var message = "Hi bot can you show me the actual weather ?";

var result = Object.keys(keyWords).find(k => 
  keyWords[k].every(word => message.includes(word)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just an other question, How can i do if I want that it match with >= 3 keywords for exemple ?

Comment: Every will compare all the words inside your keywords and only return result when it finds all of them in your string.

Comment: I get this when I run it "unique_image_url_prefixes"

Comment: @HassanImam I want to be able to find JSON  name: "key"     find key using keyword....   lets say  I want to find bob went shoe shopping, I want to type in Bob shoe as a keyword and be able to find bob went shoeshopping   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196314/fuze-js-find-name-with-keywords